# code::blocks compiler flags are being set even though they appear to not be selected

Tags: codeblocks

During a former build of my project I enabled the -std=c99 and -D_GNU_SOURCE flags in "other options" for the compiler in "build settings" in code::blocks. The next time I opened the project, those flags were not longer listed in the "other settings" box, but when I rebuilt the project they were still being used as flags for the compilation.

I no longer want those flags active, but I can't delete them or remove them because they don't appear in the "other options" box any more.

Any idea how to get rid of them?

EDIT: I was able to get rid of them by just deleting the project and redefining it from scratch. Is there a less nuclear option?